# IntelliJ Plugin with Kotlin not finding java.lang, javax.swing, etc

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am working on this IntelliJ plugin HotSwapAgent [issue](https://github.com/dmitry-zhuravlev/hotswap-agent-intellij-plugin/issues/31). I forked the code and imported it.

No matter what I do, keep having compile issues.

- The Java code can't seem to find `javax.swing.*`.
- The Kotlin code can't find `java.lang.*`.
- The plugin also relies on 2 devkit classes, `IdeaJdk` and `Sandbox`, but the `devkit` package cannot be found.

I followed the instructions for setting up my [dev environment](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/setting_up_environment.html), checking out [IntelliJ CE](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-ce/file/idea-ce-9276f4bbfb20dac51cdc0d675aef80b7f639a378/README.md), imported the project, similar to [this](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/creating_plugin_project.html).

There was a library called KotlinJavaRuntime containing the following:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="KotlinJavaRuntime">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$KOTLIN_BUNDLED$/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar!/" />
      <root url="jar://$KOTLIN_BUNDLED$/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$KOTLIN_BUNDLED$/lib/kotlin-runtime-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

I changed it to something that matches the updated Kotlin plugin, but to no avail.

All I want to do right now is get this [IntelliJ Plugin](https://github.com/dmitry-zhuravlev/hotswap-agent-intellij-plugin) out of GitHub and compile it.

Does anyone have any insight into this? Thanks!

Comment: Check if your SDK is properly configured. Also, it's recommended to use Gradle, not devkit

Comment: Is any of your java is running?. from this end, it looks like you are not configured java plugin. Please provide more details, with plugin.xml. Convert it to Gradle project it will definitely ease your development.